# Converting a short to binary...First 8 digits and last 8 digits are swapped for some reason

Tags: c++, binary, bit-manipulation, short

I'm writing a program that converts chars, shorts, and floats to binary. I got it working on chars. On shorts however, it's printing the first 8 digits after the last 8 digits. 115 should be 0000 0000 0111 0011, but my program gives me 0111 0011 0000 0000. Works fine on chars (switching i<16 to i<8).

I've spent a while searching, but can't find anything. Any hints?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;



int main()
{

char testChar = 'C';
short testShort = 115;
float testFloat = 1.99;

unsigned int mask =128;

for(int i=0; i<16;i++)
{
    //cout<<mask;
    if ((testShort & mask)==0)
        cout<<'0';
    else
        cout<<'1';
    mask >>=1;
} 

}
```

Comment: What does it mean to set `mask` to `128`?

Comment: figured it out. that was for char. shoud be 2^15 for short

Comment: Voting to close, as this problem was based on a typo.

Answer (score 0):

mask should be 32768 for short. It was 128 for char. 2^(n-1), n being the data value bits.

Comment: Consider setting `mask` to `1 << (8*sizeof(variable) - 1)`